# Delete unwanted data from api result

Tags: php, laravel, api

I have a project in laravel which has API. I'm asking the API for `posts`(I call them recommendation).

Now my api response look like this -

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": {
    "current_page": 1,
    "data": [

        {
            "id": 3,
            "course_id": "20",
            "title": "Dormouse followed.",
            "description": "Alice aloud, addres
            "file": "https://example.com/storage/images/2019/10/01/phTJ.png",
            "created_at": null,
            "updated_at": "2019-10-01 14:21:46",
            "recommendation_likes": 0,
            "is_bookmarked": "true",
            "is_liked": "false",
            "likes_count": []
        }
...
...
...
```

All is good but I don't wanna  `likes_count` to be in the result.  It is a relation method. I get from it all I need. It is if the user liked this post. And it is  `is_liked` in the result . but `likes_count` automatically added to the response .

```
 if($item->likesCount->contains($user->id)){
       $item['is_liked']='true';
 }
```

I tried delete it with

```
foreach ($recommendations as $item) {
      unset($item['likes_count']);
}
```

But it doesn't do it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is how you are referencing the object data structure. You are attempting to `unset()` something that doesn't exist so no error is thrown but the `likes_count` isn't getting removed either.

Here's your code example (fixed and modified for demonstration):

```
<?php
$apiResult = <<<eod
{
    "success": true,
    "data": {
        "current_page": 1,
        "data": [

            {
            "id": 3,
            "course_id": "20",
            "title": "Dormouse followed.",
            "description": "Alice aloud, addres",
            "file": "https://example.com/storage/images/2019/10/01/phTJ.png",
            "created_at": null,
            "updated_at": "2019-10-01 14:21:46",
            "recommendation_likes": 0,
            "is_bookmarked": "true",
            "is_liked": "false",
            "likes_count": []
            },
            {
            "id": 4,
            "course_id": "20",
            "title": "Dormouse followed.",
            "description": "Alice aloud, addres",
            "file": "https://example.com/storage/images/2019/10/01/phTJ.png",
            "created_at": null,
            "updated_at": "2019-10-01 14:21:46",
            "recommendation_likes": 0,
            "is_bookmarked": "true",
            "is_liked": "false",
            "likes_count": []
            }
        ]
    }
}
eod;

$result = json_decode($apiResult);
$data = $result->data->data;
var_dump($data);

// This should remove the likes_count array from the $result structure.
foreach ($data as &$item) {
    unset($item->likes_count);
}
var_dump($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick way would be to make that 'attribute' (relation) hidden:

```
$recommendations->makeHidden('likes_count');
```

Though I am not sure how you are building your response.